# SBT Plugin Published Locally Could not Resolve Proper Scala Version

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I wrote a simple sbt plugin which I published locally on my machine. I wanted to reference this plugin in one of my project and I ran into errors. The sbt plugin that I published had the following settings:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "openelectrons-scalafmt-common-sbt-plugin",
    version := "0.0.1",
    organization := "com.openelectrons",
    scalaVersion := "2.13.8",
    sbtPlugin := true,
    sbtVersion := "1.6.2"
  )
```

I can see in my .ivy repo that the plugin is published under scala_2.13.

I have another Scala project where I want to use this plugin for which I added it in my plugins.sbt and when I ran it using sbt, it failed as it was looking for a Scala_2.12 version of the plugin. I'm  using sbt 1.6.2. How can I force sbt to look for the sclaa_2.13 version of my plugin?

Comment: **sbt** itself uses `2.12` so you can't use a `2.13` version of a plugin, you should not even publish that.

Comment: Which scala 2.12 should I be using then?

Comment: For the plugin? I believe the latest one. For your code, none, your project can use `2.13` without any problems.